# Existence and uniqueness for the ODE $y''-y^{1/3}=0$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

For the ode $ y'' - y^{1/3}=0 $, is there any way to check the existence and uniqueness of the solution?

I know the Picard's Theorem, but it can only be used for the first order ode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Picard-Lindelöf Theorem  works just as well for systems of differential equations, which this can be converted to:

$$ \eqalign{ y' &= v\cr
             v' &= y^{1/3}\cr}$$

A more serious problem is that  $y^{1/3}$ is not Lipschitz at $y = 0$.
And indeed you don't have uniqueness there: look for solutions of the form $y(x) = c x^{3}$.

Comment: I got it, and how to choose your answer as the best answer?

Comment: if $y(0)=0, y'(0)=1$, then is there any solution?

Comment: Yes: given implicitly by $y\left( x \right) 
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}([1/2,3/4],\;[7/4],\;-3/2\, \left( y \left( x \right)  \right) ^{4/3})}
=x$.